# Assigning geometry to existing features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry, editing, features

I have a point-shape-layer with existing features and an attribute table. But none of these features have a geometry  yet(i.e. no points that are shown).
How can I now add a point to each feature? 
Ideally I want to click on a row in the attribute table and then click on the map to set that new point.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Mapping a feature from the attribute table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233981/mapping-a-feature-from-the-attribute-table-in-qgis)

Comment: I can see the benefit of this, and it's calling for a plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to the post. That was a very good solution/Workaround.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto - Doesn't ndawson's answer from the link I posted already achieve this?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that was possible.